# FInd Next smallest number with same digits Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I came across this challenge on codewars : https://www.codewars.com/kata/next-smaller-number-with-the-same-digits

It takes in an integer that can be very large. And return the next smallest integer with the same digits and returns `-1` if it doesn't exist.
I tried attempting this with brute-force, finding all permutations and finding the closest. This is obviously not efficient and results in a timeout.

What would be an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: post the code here

Comment: I think it's OK to have a language-agnostic algorithm question here--the "I tried finding all permutations" counts as an attempt. Showing the code that does it probably wouldn't help improve the question much because it's clearly hopeless.

Comment: "next smallest integer with the same digits". Does that mean the small integer should have all digits in the large integer as well?

Comment: @Austin correct, that is what the link suggests.

Comment: Here's a hint: start with the last two digits. If the right is smaller than the left of the two digits, then swapping them produces a smaller number. Can you extrapolate?

Comment: @alkasm I tried this but I've found that this gives you the smallest possible number that can be produced with the given digits. I have to find the NEXT smallest. For example trying your method on `29009` gives us `00299` whereas it should give us `20990`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Starting from the right, find the first digit that has at least one
   smaller digit to its right. We'll call that digit X.
2. Then find the largest digit that is to the right of X, and is
   smaller than X. We'll call that digit Y.
3. Swap X and Y. This makes the number smaller.
4. Then sort all of the digits to the right of Y in descending order.
   This makes the number as big as possible, without making it bigger
   than the original.

For example:

```
1262347  // original number
  ^  ^
  X  Y

1242367  // after the swap
  ^  ^
  Y  X

1247632  // after sorting digits to the right of Y
  ^
  Y
```

Comment: Awesome! Well described.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rookie attempt, and complexity is boundless, but still should be better than finding all possible combinations:

```
def swap(string, index1, index2):
    new_string = list(string)
    new_string[index1], new_string[index2] = string[index2], string[index1]
    new_string = sorted(new_string[:index1]) + new_string[index1:]
    return ''.join(new_string)

def smallest(number):
    if list(number) == sorted(number):
        return -1
    rev_num = number[::-1]
    for i, digit in enumerate(rev_num,0):
        if any(num for num in rev_num[:i] if num < digit):
            _, j = max(((num, j) for j, num in enumerate(rev_num[:i]) if int(num) < int(digit)),key = lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))
            swapped_num = swap(rev_num, i, j)
            if not swapped_num.endswith('0'):
                return int(swapped_num[::-1])
    return -1

x = ['29009','21','531','2071','9','111','135','1027','1231111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111123456789']
for i in x:
    print(smallest(i))
```

Output:

```
20990
12
513
2017
-1
-1
-1
-1
1229876543311111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```